# Add a new column based on aggregation from other two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

With the dataframe

```
(d <- data.frame(x = c(22, 2, 14, 3, 50, 11), E= rep(c('C','D'), each=3), F = rep(c('A','B'), 3)))
   x E F
1 22 C A
2  2 C B
3 14 C A
4  3 D B
5 50 D A
6 11 D B
```

I want to aggregate the column 'x' for each level of the factor 'F' as follows:

```
(y <- aggregate(x ~ F, d, function(x) x-mean(x)))
  F        x.1        x.2        x.3
1 A  -6.666667 -14.666667  21.333333
2 B  -3.333333  -2.333333   5.666667
```

What is an elegant way to use a command so that the above aggregated result can be attached to the original dataframe like the following?

```
   x E F  y
1 22 C A  -6.666667
2  2 C B  -3.333333
3 14 C A -14.666667
4  3 D B  -2.333333
5 50 D A  21.333333
6 11 D B   5.666667
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can use `ave` to apply a function to every group keeping the number of rows same.

```
d$y <- with(d, x - ave(x, F))
#Explicitly mentioning the function name
#d$y <- with(d, x - ave(x, F, FUN = mean))
d

#   x E F          y
#1 22 C A  -6.666667
#2  2 C B  -3.333333
#3 14 C A -14.666667
#4  3 D B  -2.333333
#5 50 D A  21.333333
#6 11 D B   5.666667
```

`ave` has default `FUN` argument as `mean`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Hers is on way. You define groups using `F`. For each group, you want to subtract the average value from `x`.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(d, F) %>% 
mutate(result = x - mean(x))

      x E     F     result
  <dbl> <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
1    22 C     A      -6.67
2     2 C     B      -3.33
3    14 C     A     -14.7 
4     3 D     B      -2.33
5    50 D     A      21.3 
6    11 D     B       5.67
```

If you use the data.table package, you can achieve the same thing in the following way.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, result := x - mean(x), by = F][]

    x E F     result
1: 22 C A  -6.666667
2:  2 C B  -3.333333
3: 14 C A -14.666667
4:  3 D B  -2.333333
5: 50 D A  21.333333
6: 11 D B   5.666667
```